# Should I run a learning curve before or after grid search?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, training

I would like to find out how much data I should use for training my model. I also want to test what parameters I need using grid search.

My question is should I first run a learning curve on a baseline i.e. no parameters / default ones in the model first (xgboost) or should I run learning curve straight after best model is output from grid search?

But I need to find out first the training size but am thinking maybe the learning curve will change with different parameters.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to:
1) Give some more context of the problem you are solving.
2) Clarify what you mean by learning curve.

Comment: i think what this user means is the sklearn package learning_curve